# Makefile to compile Java with external library

Tags: java, makefile

I want to write a Makefile that compiles and runs the following code. My question here is how to add an external library using Make syntax?

```
javac -cp commons-cli-1.2.jar Iperfer.java
java -cp .:commons-cli-1.2.jar Iperfer -c -h localhost -p 1234 -t 12
```

Comment: What do you mean by an external library?

Comment: A jar file: the commons-cli-1.2.jar. It's an external library.

Comment: Well, why can't you just put the above code into a Make recipe?

Comment: (And FWIW, I don't endorse using Make to build Java, given the existence of dedicated tools.)

Comment: That's not my choice buddy. I'm required to do so

Comment: Tell your teachers to get out of the dark ages.  Or change schools :-)

Answer (score 0):

> My question here is how to add an external library using Make syntax?

The Answer is in the question.  You would use the same command as you would from the command line ...

This is really a Java agnostic question.  It is really about how to write a Makefile.  But presumably if your teachers want you to use `make` to build Java, they will have provided you with a sample / template `Makefile` to get you started.  If you showed us that template, we could tell you how best to modify it.

But assuming that you don't have a specific template in mind, then this a duplicate of an existing Question.